# Overlaying alpha images on a video using ffmpeg

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, overlay, libav

I have the following ffmpeg-cli command which does not produce the described effect in documentation. Could this be a bug, or I have something wrong with the command.

```
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -i small.mp4 \
    -i monkey/monkey_%04d.png \
    -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between(t,1,5)'[out1]" \
    -map '[out1]' \
    output.mp4
```

I expect it to overlay the #1 stream on top of #0 between seconds 1 and 5.

You may download the test tarball from this link:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxIQVP1zErDPYXRveG9hN0c0Qjg/view?usp=sharing

It includes assets for the test case.

The build I tried with:

- ffmpeg-3.0.2-64bit-static (available online)

Comment: Your image sequence is 21 frames, and with ffmpeg imputing a framerate of 25, the image stream ends before the overlay starts. How fast should the images go and should they loop?

Comment: It's a test case, so they don't have to loop, and okay if finish earlier than specified in the enable option. Regardless, the output video does not have any overlay sequence, which is what I am concerned with presently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FFmpeg is a time-based processor i.e. it aligns packets by timestamps, so you have to align the start of the image sequence to the start of the overlay.

```
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -i small.mp4 \
    -i monkey/monkey_%04d.png \
    -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(1/TB)[1v]; \
    [0:v][1v]overlay=enable='between(t,1,5)'[out1]" \
    -map '[out1]' \
    output.mp4
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Could you a bit elaborate on the filter that you used for further clarification?

Comment: Sure. setpts generates new timestamps. The expression says to take the current relative timestamp `PTS-STARTPTS` and add 1 second to it. `TB` is the timebase unit i.e. the tick interval, which is the smallest time measuring unit for the video stream, so `3/TB` would represent an interval of 3 seconds.

Comment: Oh, and would it be possible to specify exact frame numbers rather than seconds as timestamps (or millisecond precision at the least)?

Because I have the frame numbers to overlay the image sequence rather than seconds (although I could easily conver them to milliseconds if necessary).

Comment: No frames, but milliseconds, yes.

Comment: Actually, frames is possible. `PTS-STARTPTS+(3/TB)+(11/FRAME_RATE*TB)` for a delay of  3s 11f

Comment: Yes, however, enable=between(n, b, e) still works with seconds as far as I can tell. In which case I should better convert my frame numbers to seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111566/discussion-between-neuro-sys-and-mulvya).

Comment: No, n works with frame index, so (n,30,40) is between 30th and 40th frame processed by the filter.